# Load last N blocks with eth-defi python

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, python

Using the web3-ethereum-defi lib and JSONRPCReorganisationMonitor how do you only load the last N blocks?  This code wants to load data from block 0 to latest.

```
reorg_mon = JSONRPCReorganisationMonitor(web3, check_depth=30)

while True:
    try:
        # Figure out the next good unscanned block range,
        # and fetch block headers and timestamps for this block range
        chain_reorg_resolution = reorg_mon.update_chain()

        if chain_reorg_resolution.reorg_detected:
            logger.info(f"Chain reorganisation data updated: {chain_reorg_resolution}")

        # Read specified events in block range
        for log_result in read_events(
            web3,
            start_block=chain_reorg_resolution.latest_block_with_good_data + 1,
            end_block=chain_reorg_resolution.last_live_block,
            filter=filter,
            notify=None,
            chunk_size=100,
            context=token_cache,
            extract_timestamps=None,
            reorg_mon=reorg_mon,
        ):
           pass
```